# Slide a list element with jQuery without effecting other list elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, html-lists

I am trying to slide up a list element and reveal more content which appears to be hidden "under" the list element, but when the animation occurs all other list elements jump down slightly. When I remove the content under the list element but leave the animation everything works fine.

How can I make this work without effecting the other elements in the list?

It is difficult for me to explain this, so here is a fiddle of what I am talking about: http://jsfiddle.net/YNBxz/1377/

click on any one of the blocks in the view section to see the animation.

If you comment out the `jQuery(this).children('.block-content').slideToggle(500);` you can see what it SHOULD look like during the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the positioning of `.block-content` to `position: absolute`. That will fix the sliding of the other `li` elements. Then, to fix the positioning of the `.block-content`, remove `width: 100%`, change the right positioning to `right: 0`, and add `top: 45px`. The css for `.block-content` is then:

```
.block-content {
    font-size: 12px;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif;
    display: block;
    background: #333;
    padding: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 45px;
    right: 0px;
    height: 120px;
}
```

Also, if you want the bottom of `.block-content` to line-up with the bottom of the `li`'s, change the jquery to animate to 140px, not 115px.

You can see the results: http://jsfiddle.net/YNBxz/1379/

Comment: Another question. How could I make it so the animation happens on hover, but doesn't retract until they click?